# how to simulate keyboard event in c++

Tags: c++, windows

I can successfully simulate some key strokes using the `keybd_event` function. But I don't know how to simulate the alphanumeric keys of the keyboard.
For example, there is a game that works by key press "d" on the keyboard. So how do I simulate this key press?

The following code works for UP arrow key.

```
keybd_event(VK_UP,0x26,0,0);
```

Comment: Use `SendInput` rather than `keybd_event`. The documentation tells you why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alphanumeric keys' virtual key codes are the same as their uppercase ASCII value.

So to press the "d" key, `keybd_event('D',...)`.

Answer (score 0):

In X11 you can do using XTestFakeKeyEvent api.

Following code will simulate F5 Key press event.

```
XTestFakeKeyEvent(display, XKeysymToKeycode(display, XK_F5), True, 0);
XTestFakeKeyEvent(display, XKeysymToKeycode(display, XK_F5), False, 0);
```